# Can we reduce the time complexity to construct a Binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

**In my yesterday's interview, i was asked time complexity to construct a binary tree from given inorder and preorder/postorder.**

I came up with skewed tree, which needs O(N^2) and somehow if we can guarantee a balanced binary tree, then we can do it in O(N log N).

**But, in order to reply unique, i came up with an idea that it can be done in O(N) time**. Reason what i gave was

1. Put one by one all the nodes of inorder traversal in hash table in O(N).
2. Searching in hash table for a particular node can be done in amortized O(1).
3. Total time complexity can be theoretically reduced to O(N). (Actually, i haven't implemented it yet)

So, was i correct in my reply and the results haven't been announced yet.

Comment: Assuming you are simply linking node pointers together, then, sure O(N), otherwise, if always traversing through the root to add a new node, then O(N log N)

Comment: Can u be more specific, sorry i didn't understand

Comment: Assuming you are storing all the nodes in hash table, how are you storing the hierarchy information like parent of a given node etc? And how will searching for a particular node in hash table will be done in O(1) ? It will take in O(N) time

Comment: For, every element lookup time in amortized hash table is O(1)

Comment: Are all the elements in the binary tree distinct? Otherwise there shall be multiple possibilities.

Comment: @stackuser got it. Thanks

Comment: @Abhishek , i assumed all distinct. And what other possibilities will be?

Comment: Each node has a left and right pointer, yes? If you can correctly link all pointers to build the tree without actually going through the methods of "is this value less than or greater than this other value - if so, go left or right" (i.e. "going through the root"), then, sure it's possible in O(N) time. However, I don't think scanning a Hashtable is going to get you that result

Comment: How will you store a traversal of a tree in a HashTable. Hashtable does not restore the ordering of the inserted elements.

Comment: you are talking of bottom up approach.

Comment: @cricket_007: `less than or greater than` - you seem to assume _search_ tree - why?

Comment: @greybeard - fair point. They are categorized as the same in my mind, but I do understand the difference

Comment: @greybeard Some search trees are binary trees (those with two children elements that are comparable in some fashion to their ancestor). A binary tree is not necessarily a search tree (no ordering is defined on the element value). I only said I think about them the same

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in `O(N)` time and `O(N)` space (for a skewed binary tree), but instead of storing the elements of inorder traversal, store the indices of the elements in the hash table. Then the following algorithm should work:

```
Function buildTree (in_index1, in_index2, pre_index1, pre_index2)
   root_index = hashEntry [pre-list[pre_index1]]
   createNode (root)
   root->leftChild = buildTree (in_index1, root_index-1, pre_index1 + 1, pre_index1 + (root_index-in_index1))
   root->rightChild = buildTree (root_index+1, in_index2, pre_index1 + (root_index-in_index1) + 1, pre_index2)
   return root
```

Note: Above is the basic idea. For the recursive calls, you will need to get the correct indices more carefully.

Comment: This is also, when there are not all distinct, right?

Comment: @stackuser If they are not distinct then how would the hash table entries be made?

Comment: we can use their indices .

Comment: @stackuser the first node in the pre-order traversal is the value of root node. If there are multiple nodes with that value, how would you get the correct root node in the inorder traversal.

Comment: Ok , thanks miseed that . got it now. your algorithm gives O(N) for even skewed tree, right?

Comment: Yes, it does hopefully.